# PHP: User status logged in or out - USER1 logged in but USER2 can logout USER1

Tags: php

I have third party application where users are going to log in or out and that application is redirecting them to regular website with username and user status (also cookie is set with username) in a URL string, which looks like:

for log in: http://www.domain.com/?username=XXXXXXXXXX&status=login

and for log out: http://www.domain.com/?username=XXXXXXXXXX&status=logout

My code to handle it looks like:

```
$username = "";
$status = "";

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$status = $_REQUEST['status'];

if(!empty($username) && !empty($status)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['status'] = $status;
}
```

and later in the main code to display welcome status and logout/login buttons:

```
if ($_SESSION['status'] == "login" && strtolower($_SESSION['username']) == strtolower($_COOKIE['username'])){ $user_status = 'in'; }
if ($_SESSION['status'] == "logout" && strtolower($_SESSION['username']) == strtolower($_COOKIE['username'])){ $user_status = 'out'; }
if ($user_status == 'in'){ ?> Welcome <?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION['username']); ?> <a href="#" class="button">Logout</a>
<?php }
elseif ($user_status == 'out' || $user_status == '') { ?> <a href="#" class="button">Login</a></div><?php } ?>
```

For an example I have successful logged in USER1 with redirect link http://www.domain.com/?username=USER1&status=login and cookie set to USER1, but when I use manual redirect link http://www.domain.com/?username=USER2&status=logout then USER1 is getting logged out despite username in URL was USER2 not USER1.

How can I prevent that situation?

Comment: Down vote for what? Is solid question with enough data provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` block in the first block of code effectively changes the logged-in user and status to whatever is in the URL. This lets anyone login or logout as anyone else.

Then, because neither of the first two `if` conditions is met in your second block of code, `$user_status` doesn't get set. So, `$user_status == null == ''`. (This is one reason that you should use `===` instead of `==`.) Therefore, the page shows the Login link.

Comment: Thanks for tips. I have move all into two `if` block checking for `$status` from the URL first then `$user_status` following with `username` vs `cookie` verification if correct user wants to log out.